# Dynamic Search Parameters Based On Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a form like so:

```
        <form name="search" class="form-search" method="get" action="http://www.bernhardt.com/search.php?">
            <div>
              <input name="search" type="text" class="search-query input-large" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)">
              <select>
                <option>Option1</option>
                <option>Option2</option>
                <option>Option3</option>
              </select>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I would like it so that when Option1 is selected, the form's input be like this:

```
<form name="search" class="form-search" method="get" action="http://www.websitehere.com/search.php?">
<div>
<input name="search" type="text" class="search-query input-large" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</div>
```

When Option2, like so:

```
<form name="search" class="form-search" method="get" action="http://www.websitehere.com/search.php?">
<div>
<input name="searchbynum" type="text" class="search-query input-large" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)">
<input type="hidden" name="searchbydesc" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="Submit" value="Go" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</div>
```

So no and so forth with other options. I do understand that a fair bit of Javascript is required here, but I don't know how (I know basic HTML and CSS, not so much Javascript). I would appreciate any help on this topic.

Comment: What does your submitenter method do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at document.createElement()

You should be able to do:

```
<script>
function addInputs() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    document.getElementById("frm").appendChild(input);
}
</script>

<form id="frm">
<select onchange="addInputs()" id="sel">
<option>Option 1</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: This adds a new text input - I want it to change the existing text input. Also, how would I have the form refer to the correct Option's search parameters?

Comment: To change an existing text input, you can modify it's attributes. For example in addInputs() you could do something like the following

document.getElementById('input').value = "foo";
document.getElementById('input').className = "barClass";
This should list the available properties in HTML4: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp
HTML5 offers a lot of neat stuff as well.

To reference the options value, you can use select.option[select.selectedIndex]
This will show the available properties for the select: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp